# Deserializing a class with a generic type parameter using JsonConvert in C#

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconvert

I have a somewhat complex class hierarchy which I am attempting to deserialize using `JsonConvert`.

This is an extremely contrived example of what I'm trying to do. Note that:

- I am not able to modify the `Deserializable` class, and I must inherit from it specifically.
- I am not able to modify the deserialization code itself.

#### Classes

```cs
namespace Animals {
    // cannot modify these
    public class Deserializable {}
    abstract class Region {}
    public class Africa : Region {}
    public class America : Region {}
    public class Europe : Region {}
    public class Australia : Region {}

    // can modify these
    public abstract class Animal : Deserializable {}
    public class Cow<T> : Animal where T : Region {}
    public class AngusCow : Cow<Australia> {}
    public class AurochCow : Cow<Europe> {}
    // I don't know any other cow types
}
```

#### The JSON I'm trying to deserialize

```json
[
    { "$type": "Animals.AngusCow, Animals" },
    { "$type": "Animals.AurochCow, Animals" },
]
```

#### Deserialization Options

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
serializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
serializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
serializerSettings.MaxDepth = new int?(50);
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().ContractResolver;
```

The deserialization code:

```cs
var animals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Deserializable>>(jsonString, serializerSettings);
```

My guess is that it's the `Cow<T>` part that's tripping it up, or maybe `Cow<Australia>`. Is there anything I need to put in the JSON itself to fix this? It's possible I could write this code without it needing the type parameter, but in my case I would prefer it to use one if I can.

The error is this:

```
Error resolving type specified in JSON 'Animals.AngusCow, Animals'.
```

And this is using the [Json.NET library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).

I can confirm that there is nothing wrong with the assembly name or even the type name, as in my actual code I have other '`Animals`' contained within the json list - ones that don't have type parameters such as the `Cow<T>` - and they deserialize fine when the breaking types are not included in the list.

---

**Edit**: After further investigation, I removed the type parameter from Cow. I still ran into the same error.

For perhaps a simple example, the class hierarchy is:

```
Deserializable > A > B > X: Works
Deserializable > A > B > Y: Works
Deserializable > A > B > Z: Works
Deserializable > A > B > C > D: Does not work
Deserializable > A > B > C > E: Does not work
Deserializable > A > B > C > F: Does not work
```

Where `A`, `B` and `C` are all abstract.

This points to `C` being the problem class, however, `C` doesn't have any fields on it - so there can't be any problems with field deserialization.

Comment: Could just be a typo, but `Animals.AngusCow, Animal` is not `Animals.AngusCow, Animals`.

Comment: In the full type name, after the comma is the assembly's name. But the error output display `..., Animal` and in the json example is `..., Animals`.

Comment: Hey, the assembly name equivalent is Animals. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a typo in the class namespace (in the C# files).